# Powershell created excel-oject is null

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using a powershell script to read a pdf-file and create a excel list. Two years ago it was running well but now I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:1
+ $workbook = $excelobj.workbooks.add()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Then I tried to create ony the excel file by using a shell, which I started as an admin and exectue this lines.

```
$excelobj = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $excelobj.workbooks.add()
```

After executing the second line I get the same error.

This is what I get, when I open the object.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $excelobj


Application                          :
Creator                              :
Parent                               :
ActiveCell                           :
ActiveChart                          :
ActiveDialog                         :
ActiveMenuBar                        :
ActivePrinter                        :
ActiveSheet                          :
ActiveWindow                         :
ActiveWorkbook                       :
AddIns                               :
Assistant                            :
Cells                                :
Charts                               :
Columns                              :
CommandBars                          :
DDEAppReturnCode                     :
DialogSheets                         :
MenuBars                             :
Modules                              :
Names                                :
Rows                                 :
Selection                            :
Sheets                               :
ThisWorkbook                         :
Toolbars                             :
Windows                              :
Workbooks                            :
WorksheetFunction                    :
Worksheets                           :
Excel4IntlMacroSheets                :
Excel4MacroSheets                    :
AlertBeforeOverwriting               :
AltStartupPath                       :
AskToUpdateLinks                     :
EnableAnimations                     :
AutoCorrect                          :
Build                                :
CalculateBeforeSave                  :
Calculation                          :
CanPlaySounds                        :
CanRecordSounds                      :
Caption                              :
CellDragAndDrop                      :
DisplayClipboardWindow               :
ColorButtons                         :
CommandUnderlines                    :
ConstrainNumeric                     :
CopyObjectsWithCells                 :
Cursor                               :
CustomListCount                      :
CutCopyMode                          :
DataEntryMode                        :
_Default                             :
DefaultFilePath                      :
Dialogs                              :
DisplayAlerts                        :
DisplayFormulaBar                    :
DisplayFullScreen                    :
DisplayNoteIndicator                 :
DisplayCommentIndicator              :
DisplayExcel4Menus                   :
DisplayRecentFiles                   :
DisplayScrollBars                    :
DisplayStatusBar                     :
EditDirectlyInCell                   :
EnableAutoComplete                   :
EnableCancelKey                      :
EnableSound                          :
EnableTipWizard                      :
FileSearch                           :
FileFind                             :
FixedDecimal                         :
FixedDecimalPlaces                   :
Height                               :
IgnoreRemoteRequests                 :
Interactive                          :
Iteration                            :
LargeButtons                         :
Left                                 :
LibraryPath                          :
MailSession                          :
MailSystem                           :
MathCoprocessorAvailable             :
MaxChange                            :
MaxIterations                        :
MemoryFree                           :
MemoryTotal                          :
MemoryUsed                           :
MouseAvailable                       :
MoveAfterReturn                      :
MoveAfterReturnDirection             :
RecentFiles                          :
Name                                 :
NetworkTemplatesPath                 :
ODBCErrors                           :
ODBCTimeout                          :
OnCalculate                          :
OnData                               :
OnDoubleClick                        :
OnEntry                              :
OnSheetActivate                      :
OnSheetDeactivate                    :
OnWindow                             :
OperatingSystem                      :
OrganizationName                     :
Path                                 :
PathSeparator                        :
PivotTableSelection                  :
PromptForSummaryInfo                 :
RecordRelative                       :
ReferenceStyle                       :
RollZoom                             :
ScreenUpdating                       :
SheetsInNewWorkbook                  :
ShowChartTipNames                    :
ShowChartTipValues                   :
StandardFont                         :
StandardFontSize                     :
StartupPath                          :
StatusBar                            :
TemplatesPath                        :
ShowToolTips                         :
Top                                  :
DefaultSaveFormat                    :
TransitionMenuKey                    :
TransitionMenuKeyAction              :
TransitionNavigKeys                  :
UsableHeight                         :
UsableWidth                          :
UserControl                          :
UserName                             :
Value                                :
VBE                                  :
Version                              :
Visible                              :
Width                                :
WindowsForPens                       :
WindowState                          :
UILanguage                           :
DefaultSheetDirection                :
CursorMovement                       :
ControlCharacters                    :
EnableEvents                         :
DisplayInfoWindow                    :
ExtendList                           :
OLEDBErrors                          :
COMAddIns                            :
DefaultWebOptions                    :
ProductCode                          :
UserLibraryPath                      :
AutoPercentEntry                     :
LanguageSettings                     :
Dummy101                             :
AnswerWizard                         :
CalculationVersion                   :
ShowWindowsInTaskbar                 :
FeatureInstall                       :
Ready                                :
FindFormat                           :
ReplaceFormat                        :
UsedObjects                          :
CalculationState                     :
CalculationInterruptKey              :
Watches                              :
DisplayFunctionToolTips              :
AutomationSecurity                   :
DisplayPasteOptions                  :
DisplayInsertOptions                 :
GenerateGetPivotData                 :
AutoRecover                          :
Hwnd                                 :
Hinstance                            :
ErrorCheckingOptions                 :
AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks :
SmartTagRecognizers                  :
NewWorkbook                          :
SpellingOptions                      :
Speech                               :
MapPaperSize                         :
ShowStartupDialog                    :
DecimalSeparator                     :
ThousandsSeparator                   :
UseSystemSeparators                  :
ThisCell                             :
RTD                                  :
DisplayDocumentActionTaskPane        :
ArbitraryXMLSupportAvailable         :
MeasurementUnit                      :
ShowSelectionFloaties                :
ShowMenuFloaties                     :
ShowDevTools                         :
EnableLivePreview                    :
DisplayDocumentInformationPanel      :
AlwaysUseClearType                   :
WarnOnFunctionNameConflict           :
FormulaBarHeight                     :
DisplayFormulaAutoComplete           :
GenerateTableRefs                    :
Assistance                           :
EnableLargeOperationAlert            :
LargeOperationCellThousandCount      :
DeferAsyncQueries                    :
MultiThreadedCalculation             :
ActiveEncryptionSession              :
HighQualityModeForGraphics           :
FileExportConverters                 :
SmartArtLayouts                      :
SmartArtQuickStyles                  :
SmartArtColors                       :
AddIns2                              :
PrintCommunication                   :
UseClusterConnector                  :
ClusterConnector                     :
Quitting                             :
Dummy22                              :
Dummy23                              :
ProtectedViewWindows                 :
ActiveProtectedViewWindow            :
IsSandboxed                          :
SaveISO8601Dates                     :
HinstancePtr                         :
FileValidation                       :
FileValidationPivot                  :
ShowQuickAnalysis                    :
QuickAnalysis                        :
FlashFill                            :
EnableMacroAnimations                :
ChartDataPointTrack                  :
FlashFillMode                        :
MergeInstances                       :
EnableCheckFileExtensions            :
```

In the last two years my company change to Excel 365, but I can't find any difference on google in the usage of the excel objects.

Comment: It's `Workbooks` (plural), not `workbook` (singular): `$excelobj.Workbooks.Add()`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the error is still there

Comment: _"which I started as an admin"_ You should be running as a user that already has opened Excel at least once after installation

Comment: Try to set $excelobj.visible=1 right after creating it. This way you might see what's going on.

Comment: I startet a powershell commando window with "run as administrator" and executed these two lines. Excel 365 is running well on my PC.

Comment: @ThomasMX After executing `$excelobj.visible=1` I get another error and excel doesn't open a window.

Comment: Looking at your `$excelobj` output it doesn't look like the Com Object has been created successfully, as when I do this, I can see information for each of the properties listed. When creating the COM object try specifying the `-Verbose` switch to see if there's confirmation of the instance type being 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass': `$excelobj = New-Object -ComObject excel.application -Verbose`

Comment: It also occurs to me that perhaps it's still trying to load the previous version of excel, so try forcing the newed excel version with `$excelobj = New-Object -ComObject excel.application.16 -Verbose`

Comment: @NiMux  Now I got more information, but I don't understand it. After executing with `-verbose` I get this message: The object in the pipeline is an instanz from typ "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" out of the interop-assembly of the component. If this typ is using other elements as the IDispatch-Elemente, scripts may not work unless the primary interop-assembly is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found at least a workaround for my problem. The powershell script is now working on a pc with an installation of excel 2013.